# Conditional Specialization

Tags: c++, c++20

Suppose I have the following:

```
template<std::size_t> struct s;
template<> struct s<sizeof(int)>  { /*...*/ };
template<> struct s<sizeof(long)> { /*...*/ }; // will not compile as it already exists.
```

How do I implement a check to differentiate the two instantiations conditionally? I only want to implement the latter if and only if they are not equal.

Obviously, `sizeof` is not a construct that can be evaluated by the pre-processor. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both the specialisations take an (unconstrained) `std::size_t`, and only enable the specialization if it `== sizeof(int)` or `== sizeof(long) && sizeof(long) != sizeof(int)`:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t, typename = void> struct s;

template<std::size_t N>
struct s<N, std::enable_if_t<N == sizeof(int)>> { /* ... */ };

template<std::size_t N>
struct s<N, std::enable_if_t<N != sizeof(int) && N == sizeof(long)>> { /* ... */ };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can reserve an “invalid” value, you can substitute it to avoid the collision:

```
template<std::size_t> struct s;
template<> struct s<sizeof(int)> { /*...*/ };
template<> struct s<sizeof(long)==sizeof(int) ? -1 : sizeof(long)> { /*...*/ };
```

It’s also sometimes possible to use `if constexpr` instead of explicit specializations, such that the duplication is not an error.